# I lost my French student visa

Tags: schengen-visas

I lost my passport with French student visa and now I got new passport through VFS office paris and they said contact prefecture de police for French student visa stamping.

I visited more than four prefecture but I didn't get a solution. I don't know what to do next and how to stamp visa in my new passport... anybody know?

Comment: This belongs on [Expatriates.SE].  Have you asked anyone at your school?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any official definitive answer, but sampling from various traveller's forum (based on the assumption that you don't have a temporary resident card, which would involve a different procedure) :

- If not already done, you must fill a 'déclaration de perte ou vol' at a police station.
- the consulate that gave you the visa is ultimately responsible for re-issuing it.
- some people mention going to the prefecture that will then contact the issuing consulate to get a copy/proof of your visa and stick it on the new passport. It seems that many times, they don't want to bother dealing with this, this could explain why you get nonconclusive answers at the prefectures you visited.
- have you tried to directly contact the issuing consulate ?